# Error when registering a csv file as an mltable on Azure ML: "A well-defined MLTable file was not found at the root of the selected folder."

Tags: azure, yaml, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

I have a csv file and I need to register it as an mltable dataset on AzureML by uploading a local folder.
I can't seem to set the MLTable file correctly though, and I get the following error:
"A well-defined MLTable file was not found at the root of the selected folder."

[image]

My MLTable file is very basic:

```
type: mltable
paths: 
  - pattern: ./*.csv
```

My csv file is as follows:

```
,canale,cluster_agenzia,eta,settore_merceologico,listino_proposto,cluster_soc_vend_prec,zona,tipo_pagamento,categoria_cespite,FLAG
0,3,0,58.0,1,5,2,1,2,2,SI
1,3,0,69.0,0,9,0,1,1,3,NO
2,5,0,65.0,1,8,2,2,0,2,NO
3,3,0,54.0,0,6,3,2,0,3,NO
4,3,2,26.0,0,7,3,1,0,3,NO
5,2,0,47.0,1,5,0,2,2,2,NO
6,5,0,64.0,0,6,0,2,2,3,SI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MLTable file should be named *exactly* as MLTable - no filename extension. You have MLTable.yaml, which is not allowed.